# Subsetting mutliband raster in QGIS using OTB BandMathX

Tags: qgis, multi-band, otb-applications

I am attempting to do a simple extraction of a multiband (360 bands) raster in QGIS. I have come to the conclusion I need to use BandMathX from OTB, since I am interested in generating a new multiband raster with the values from the previous, above a certain value, in this case -1.5.

I have tried using the following in QGIS (this is copypasted from the log-file):

```
{ 'il' : ['dir/file.tif'], 'out' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'exp' : 'im1>{-1.5}', 'incontext' : '', 'outcontext' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'outputpixeltype' : 5 }

2021-03-31 11:18:48 (INFO) BandMathX: Using expression: im1>{-1.5}

2021-03-31 11:18:48 (FATAL) BandMathX: itk::ERROR: 

ParserXImpl(0000021924F14460):

Message: Can't evaluate function/operator ">": Internal error.

Formula: im1>{-1.5}

Token: >

Position: 3
```

I have read the section on BandMathX in the OTB CookBook and I cannot see how the expression is in valid.

I have also tried using the same expression without the '{}'.

I hope some of you guys can help me out. I have already been searchin for similar posts, but were unable to find any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to to that with `BandMahX` directly from man-made expression.

Not really answering, but a workaround that can help sometimes: I usually end up with a script that writes the expression for me.

## Command line

Binary multi band raster, with 0 when the value is <=-1.5, and 1 else:

```
otbcli_BandMathX -il image.tif -exp $(python -c "n=360; t=-1.5; print('{' + ';'.join(['im1b{}>{}?1:0'.format(b, t) for b in range(1,n+1)]) + '}')") -out out_image.tif
```

Raster with 0 where the value is <= -1.5, and the original value else:

```
otbcli_BandMathX -il image.tif -exp $(python -c "n=360; t=-1.5; print('{' + ';'.join(['im1b{b}>{t}?im1b{b}:0'.format(b=b, t=t) for b in range(1,n+1)]) + '}')") -out out_image.tif
```

## OTB Python API

We can do the same thing using the OTB python API (Also we can retrieve the number of channels).

```
import otbApplication

t = -1.5
in_raster = '/pat/to/input_raster.tif'
out_raster = '/pat/to/output_raster.tif'

# Get input image number of channels
info = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("ReadImageInfo")
info.SetParameterString("in", in_raster)
info.Execute()
n = info.GetParameterInt("numberbands")

# Generate the muparser expression
exp = '{' + ';'.join(['im1b{b}>{t}?im1b{b}:0'.format(b=b, t=t) for b in range(1,n+1)]) + '}'

# Use BandMath to apply the expression
bm = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("BandMath")
bm.SetParameterString("exp", exp)
bm.SetParameterStringList("il", [in_raster])
bm.SetParameterString("out", out_raster)
bm.ExecuteAndWriteOutput()
```

Comment: Thank you, since I am new to both QGIS and Python I do not really know how to incorporate your workaround, is it done within python Console or how ist it done?

Comment: My workaround is a command line in bash (Linux, Mac). I dont know how it can translate in windows, but it should be doable. The `python -c "n=360; t=-1.5; print('{' + ';'.join(['im1b{b}>{t}?im1b{b}:0'.format(b=b, t=t) for b in range(1,n+1)]) + '}')"` thing just generates some output containing the BandMath expression. I'll edit my answer to add some more pythonic way.